# Find all objects with same property in array PHP

Tags: php

I am having a bit of difficulty testing one array against another.

I have a persons array

```
    0 => 
     object(Prospect)[196]
     private 'firstname' => string 'Jane' 
     private 'surname' => string 'Doe' 
     private 'email' => string 'test@test.com' 
     private 'postcode' => string 'LS' 
     public 'region' => string 'Yorkshire' 
   1 => 
     object(Prospect)[197]
     private 'firstname' => string 'John' 
     private 'surname' => string 'Doe' 
     private 'email' => string 'test1@test.com' 
     private 'postcode' => string 'CH' 
     public 'region' => string 'Cheshire'
```

and a jobs array

```
    0 => 
      object(Job)[2]
      private 'title' => string 'Job 1' 
      private 'ref' => string '0001' 
      private 'postcode' => string 'CH' 
      public 'region' => string 'Cheshire' 
      private 'wage' => string '£250' 
    1 => 
      object(Job)[3]
      private 'title' => string 'Job 2' 
      private 'ref' => string '0002' 
      private 'postcode' => string 'CH'
      public 'region' => string 'Cheshire'
      private 'wage' => string '£200.00'
```

What is the best way to iterate over each person in the persons array to find all jobs in the jobs array that have the same region for that particular person?

**Edit:** The data that I am working with is large on the prospect side and the job side, the above is just an example of the data that I am working with.

My overall goal for this is to be able to link each prospect with up to 6 jobs in the same region and then output this data into CSV file(s) to be used in a third party email campaign service.

I am quite new to this so would be grateful of any help

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  do you have `accessor`(getter) methods for your `private` properties?

Comment: Can't you just do such a selection in the data model, e.g. via SQL?

Comment: If you have to do this in PHP rather than in the database, then the array_filter() function may be useful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$persons_region = 'Cheshire';

$found_jobs = array();
foreach ($jobs as $job) {
    if ($job['region'] == $persons_region) {
        $found_jobs[] = $job;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the simpliest but maybe slowest way is

```
$job_ids = array();
foreach($persons_array as $person) {
  foreach ($jobs_array as $id=>$job) {
    if ($person->region == $job->region) $job_ids[] = $id;
  }
}
```

so you can do

```
foreach ($job_ids as $id) {
  // whatever using $id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea, however I am working with alot of data on the person and job side so might cause issues. My person data comes from a CSV file and the jobs come from a json feed, in that case for speed and best practice would I be better putting the data into datbase tables first then query that

Comment: up to you, if you show me this tables structure, I can help you to compose a correct SQL query

Comment: thanks, I have not created a table structure yet as i was trying to avoid using a database as the data changes regularly and would need to delete and create and delete records dynamically from the CSV file and Json feed. My end goal is to have a CSV file(s) with 1 person that has 6 jobs in their region linked to them, do you think this is possible?.

Comment: @James everything is possible, can you, please, edit your question?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by edit the question, do you mean the original question or my comment on this answer?